# "The English grammar" or "English grammar"

Tags: american-english, definite-article, british-english, zero-article

Should we use definite article (the) before "English grammar".

Please tell me which sentence is perfect:

> Tenses in the English grammar.
>
> Tenses in English grammar.

Answer (score 6):

Without the context of a full sentence I will say it depends.

> I find it difficult to learn tenses in English grammar:

because it is English grammar in **general**.

> The way I was taught the different tenses in the English grammar I was
>   taught at school isn't proving very effective:

because it is not English grammar in general but the **particular** grammar I was taught.

Note that not using the word "grammar" would not change anything, you can say "tenses in English" and everybody knows what it means.

Answer (score 1):

The clearest and quickest formula would be "English tenses", I think. But "tenses in English" is good and sufficient. To express the idea that tenses are in a grammar book is actually not necessary, it is self-evident.